# Why is Pressflow not listed under Drupal.org's List of distributions?

Tags: community-official-site

I'm curious why it isn't listed under distributions. Is it because they have made modifications to the drupal core?

Comment: It's a fork, not distro.

Comment: @Mołot It is mentioned as both distro and fork in the official site.

Answer (score 2):

Press-flow generally takes the established features of the next version of Drupal and back-ports it to the current version.

For example Pressflow-6 Takes the features(enhancements and performance improvements) from Drupal-7 and back-ports it Drupal-6. These changes generally include changing the core to considerable amount.

The only reason I think of why it is not included is that

> Since it makes changes to the core it doesn't make sense to host it on
>   the Drupal.org under project.